# Java - Possible to create a new class without bytecode while running?

Tags: java

I was wondering if it was possible to basically create a new class file while running without bytecode manipulation. (ex ASM, BCEL, etc). I was thinking something along the lines of a txt file transforming into a .java file and then compiling.

Comment: a .java file is a text file with a different extension. Look into Compiler tools in JDK

Comment: You mean like running a shell command for javac ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open a .txt/.java file containing a class, and using reflection on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868892/is-it-possible-to-open-a-txt-java-file-containing-a-class-and-using-reflectio)

Comment: write a java file, compile it with javac and load it at runtime

Answer (score 3):

You can create a .java file of it and Compile it on Runtime. For example:

```
String fileToCompile = "test" + java.io.File.separator +"MyClass.java";
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
    if(compilationResult == 0){
        System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
    }
}
```

Though, this only works when the Runtime environment is a JDK. You could of course, use the javac function to handle this.

Comment: So you can create a .java file and compile it all on runtime? Basically I want a way to modify packages before compiling. I am building against something that refactors package names every version, and want to get around having to update every version. The only problem is that they say I cannot use bytecode manipulation. I also cannot use backdoors or websites.

Comment: This is more of a compile time activity than a runtime.  I'd just create a code generation section of your ant script to create a version by manipulating the package of the file, then let the normal compilation process package up the jar file as apart of the build process.  No special API to compile things, no dynamic proxies, bytecode libs, scripting languages, etc.  Well you might write a script to regex the files and change the package names. :-)

Comment: It is possible. I made a sourcing of something that is similar a while ago: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4p4borsfkiwg5yh/Td4C4-I4AC

Comment: There is a problem, this has to be able to run without JDK, so I need another way to run this.

Comment: Then use the link I provided in the 3rd comment. They do need JDK for that though. It is very hard to compile without it. You could always send to a server though,

Comment: @JNorr44: You're asking to get `.java` files compiled and loaded at runtime...without the JDK.  That's simply not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just gonna try to do some light bytecode manipulation and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).

> Unlike other similar bytecode editors, Javassist provides two levels
>   of API: source level and bytecode level. If the users use the
>   source-level API, they can edit a class file without knowledge of the
>   specifications of the Java bytecode.

Comment: The source compiler is not hard to use, and does not require javac

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [dynamic proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). From the documentation:

> A dynamic proxy class (simply referred to as a proxy class below) is a class that implements a list of interfaces specified at runtime when the class is created, with behavior as described below. A proxy interface is such an interface that is implemented by a proxy class. A proxy instance is an instance of a proxy class. Each proxy instance has an associated invocation handler object, which implements the interface InvocationHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but it really depends on what you are trying to do as to what technology you choose.  It might not involve writing actual Java code.  For example, you could write any one of the scripting languages that run on the JVM: Groovy, Scala, Clojure, Jython, jRuby, Javascript, and those can be compiled to byte code.  Groovy is the closest thing to Java syntax.  The big advantage here is they can be modified and rerun without having to reload their bytecode because they are interpreted.  But most options have a bytecode compliation for speed.