# Get method as a file from .java file

Tags: java, algorithm, file, arraylist, reflection

I have a .java file in a folder. I want to get all the methods and every method as a separate file.

```
class Foo{
public void add(int a, int b){ System.out.println(a+b);}
private int sub(int a, int b,int c){ return a-b;}}
```

In my program, I want to get all the methods  add , sub as separate two files. I know this for `.class` file.we can achieve it using Reflection, but is it possible for .java file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to open a .txt/.java file containing a class, and using reflection on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868892/is-it-possible-to-open-a-txt-java-file-containing-a-class-and-using-reflectio)

Comment: Sure. You'll need to write a simple parser to get the methods, but that's just programming, and not even too difficult.

Comment: @NomadMaker thanks for helping me. But in which place I add parser? in a file there are different types of methods like public, private and it may be void or there may be return type.pls explain me

Comment: @Oliver thanks for your feedback. But I want to get all methods as a separate file from a .java file. –

Comment: @SanzidaSultana what did you mean by `I want to get all methods as a separate file from a .java file`?

Comment: @reyad thanks for your feedback. In my code, there are two methods named add and sub.I want to create two separate files like **add.java** which contain the method body "add(int a, int b){ System.out.println(a+b);}" and another file **sub.java** which contain "sub(int a, int b,int c){ return a-b;}".

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, you don't need reflection for that...you need to write some parser that could extract methods from a class in java...and you can write the parser in any language...

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206065/java-parse-java-source-code-extract-methods).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java : parse java source code, extract methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206065/java-parse-java-source-code-extract-methods)

Comment: @reyad  I have a project going on where I can't use any kind of software and I am also a beginner. can you pls explain to me step by step how I will do that? It will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, I've added an answer, pls look and tell me if it works for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SanzidaSultana, I've provided the code to extract the methods from a class...This uses regex to extract method from class file. But, this implementation has limitation. Anyway, it'll help you solve your problems. I am just providing the code below(with example).

The parser I've provided, it's very easy to use. All you need is the `JavaMethodParser` class. Just use it to extract method(with it's name!). See below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Note: it is very simple parser
 *       as simple as possible
 *       it's assuming Foo.java is correctly written
 *       it can only track a few errors in Foo.java
 *       is not written in proper format
 *       so, keep that in mind
 *
 *
*/

class JavaMethodParser {
    private List<String> methodList;
    private List<String> methodNameList;
    private int cnt;
    
    public JavaMethodParser(String classContents) {
        Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*\\s*class\\s+([_a-zA-Z]+)\\s*\\{(.*)}$", Pattern.DOTALL);
        
        // now match
        Matcher classMatcher = classPattern.matcher(classContents);

        if(classMatcher.find()) {
            String methodContents = classMatcher.group(2);

            // now parse the methods
            Pattern methodPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s+([_a-zA-Z]+)\\s*?\\(.*?\\)\\s*?\\{", Pattern.DOTALL);

            Matcher methodMatcher = methodPattern.matcher(methodContents);

            List<String> methodStartList = new ArrayList<>();

            // creating method list and methodName list
            methodList = new ArrayList<>();
            methodNameList = new ArrayList<>();

            while(methodMatcher.find()) {
                String methodName = methodMatcher.group(1);
                String methodStart = methodMatcher.group();
                methodStartList.add(methodStart);
                methodNameList.add(methodName);
            }

            // reversing, cause it'll be easier to split
            // methods from the end of methodContents
            Collections.reverse(methodStartList);
            Collections.reverse(methodNameList);
            
            String buf = methodContents;
            int i=0;
            for(String methodStart: methodStartList) {
                String[] t = buf.split(Pattern.quote(methodStart));
                String method = methodStart + t[1];
                
                methodList.add(method);
                
                buf = t[0];
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("error: class not found");
            // throw error, cause not even a class
            // or do whatever you think necessary
        }

        // initializing cnt
        cnt = -1;
    }
    public boolean hasMoreMethods() {
        cnt += 1; // cause, cnt is initialized with -1
        return cnt < methodList.size();
    }
    public String getMethodName() {
        return methodNameList.get(cnt);
    }
    public String getMethod() {
        return methodList.get(cnt);
    }
    public int countMethods() {
        return methodList.size();
    }
}

public class SOTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Foo.java"));
            String classContents = in.useDelimiter("\\Z").next().trim();

            JavaMethodParser jmp = new JavaMethodParser(classContents);

            while(jmp.hasMoreMethods()) {
                System.out.println("name: " + jmp.getMethodName());
                System.out.println("definition:\n" + jmp.getMethod());
                System.out.println();
            }

            in.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The input to this program is **Foo.java** which is written as below:

```
public class Foo {
    
    private int u, v;
    private String x;
    
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        if(a + b < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return a + b;
    }
    
    public int sub(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
name: sub
definition:
public int sub(int a, int b) {
                return a - b;
        }


name: add
definition:
public int add(int a, int b) {
                if(a + b < 0) {
                        return 0;
                }
                return a + b;
        }
```

I guess, you know how to write something in file using java. So, I will left that part to you...

[P.S.]: If anything is unclear to you, let me know in the comment section...also provide feedback if its working or not for you...

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, sorry for being late...got stuck into some task....read the answer above and tell me if that works for you...

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, its not probably appropriate to ask in SO, but I'll ask anyway...are you from Bangladesh, India or may be Pakistaan?...Your name has a subcontinental touch...

Comment: Sorry for late. Thanks for your answer. I am trying this with the code you provided and I will tell you if it is working for me or not. and I am Bangladeshi.

Comment: It's showing me **error: class not found** every time though I pass Foo.java file by scanner class. I think it may be possible only for the class file. I 'm confused

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, Have you created a file `Foo.java` and put it in the same directory as `SOTest.java`? Its perectly working in my pc...what is your java version? Give me your directory structure...

Comment: java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: I created a file Foo.java.And when i print the classContents from the main method its print the file contents.the output is: **class Foo{
public void add(int a, int b){ System.out.println(a+b);}
private int sub(int a, int b,int c){ return a-b;}}
error: class not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Search.JavaMethodParser.hasMoreMethods(JavaMethodParser.java:76)
 at Search.SOTest.main(SOTest.java:17)
C:\Users\Tech Land\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED  **

Comment: wait a min...i'm updatng the code...my regex requires very tight match....i am loosing it a bit

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, I've edited the code....now copy paste the code and test...its working for your input too...and give me feedback as soon as possible...

Comment: Its worked. Thanksss for your effort.

Comment: @SanzidaSultana, you're welcome..have a good day...